# html positioning - text overlapping other text

Tags: html, css, position, html-lists

In order to get what I want do I need to make another ul element or is it possible to do it with one?

Code is below:

HTML

```
<body>
    <p>
        <b>text</b>text<br /> 
        <b>text</b>text<br />               
        <b>text</b>text<br /> 
        <b>text</b>
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
   </ul>
   <p>
       <b>text</b>text<br /> 
       <b>text</b>text<br />                
       <b>text</b>text<br /> 
       <b>text</b>
   </p>
   <ul>
       <li>text</li>
       <li>text</li>
   </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @D0nK3Y_D0nK, could you please respond to the answers below? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works for you:

Wrap your `ul` in a div:

```
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>text</li>
      <li>text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and in CSS:

```
.list {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

snippet given below:

```css
p {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 50px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
.list {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>
    <b>text</b>text
    <br />
    <b>text</b>text
    <br />
    <b>text</b>text
    <br />
    <b>text</b>
  </p>
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>text</li>
      <li>text</li>
      <li>text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>
    <b>text</b>text
    <br />
    <b>text</b>text
    <br />
    <b>text</b>text
    <br />
    <b>text</b>
  </p>
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>text</li>
      <li>text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the html.

```
<p>
    <b>text</b>text<br /> 
    <b>text</b>text<br />               
    <b>text</b>text<br /> 
    <b>text</b>
</p>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
<p>
   <b>text</b>text<br /> 
   <b>text</b>text<br />                
   <b>text</b>text<br /> 
   <b>text</b>
</p>
   <li>text</li>
   <li>text</li>
```

And the CSS.

```
p {
    text-align: left;
    margin:50px;
    line-height:15px;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    width:100%; 
}

li{
   text-align:right;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I tried what you suggested its done what I want but its too far left  (http://imgur.com/qxTJ0Hd) how would I position it more right? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple adjustment to the UL tag in your CSS should do the trick.

CSS:

```
ul {
    position: relative;
    right: 40px;  /* Adjust number to push away from the right side */
    float: right;
    list-style-type: disic;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

[See jfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1f5ycxLu/6/)